# How to use the first image sequence in a multiple cropping process in ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

I want resize, crop and concatenate really many images. 
I don't want to write the intermediate results to disk, just the final result only.

My script is :

```
montage -mode concatenate \
\( test.jpg -thumbnail "150x100>" -background white -gravity center -extent 150x100 -page 150x100+0+0 \) \
\( -clone 0 -crop 23x16+80+0  -background white -extent 23x16 \)  \
\( -clone 0 -crop 23x16+16+87 -background white -extent 23x16 \) \
...
-delete 0 -quality 100% thumb.jpg
```

I got always the following error:

```
montage.im6: geometry does not contain image `test.jpg' @ warning/transform.c/CropImage/574.
```

I tried to use the "repage" and "page" parameters, but I was unsuccessful with them.

Any idea?

**Update**

Mark asked for examples. So I try to write down the different steps which I would like to merge in one single step:

```
convert logo: test.jpg

convert test.jpg -thumbnail "150x100>" -background white -gravity center -extent 150x100 -page 150x100+0+0 test.resized.jpg

montage -mode concatenate test.resized.jpg \
    \( -clone 0 -crop 23x16+80+20  -background white -extent 23x16 \) \
    \( -clone 0 -crop 23x16+92+74 -background white -extent 23x16 \) \
    \( -clone 0 -crop 23x16+100+80 -background white -extent 23x16 \) \
    -delete 0 -quality 100% result.thumb.jpg
```

And the results:
[you can see here the expected result](http://phspring.nl/stackoverflow28101334.jpg).

http://phspring.nl/stackoverflow28101334.jpg

Comment: Mmmm... how about showing us your input image(s) and how the output is supposed to look so we don't have to guess.

Comment: Hi Mark, I updated my question with a few more information and with the link of expected result example :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must admit this one has me mystified! I cannot get it to work how you tried, or how I would want to do it at all. I found that I can only make it work if I add a `+repage` but if I do that it *forgets* the `-extent`, so I keep ending up with 2 commands. I also find that `+clone` refuses to work in place of `-clone 0` for this example, which also mystifies me.

The only way I can make it work, and avoid the intermediate file is to stream the output of the first `convert` to the second one.

```
convert logo: -resize "150x100>" -background white -gravity center -extent 150x100 JPG:- | \
    convert JPG:- \
       \( -clone 0 -crop 23x16+80+20  \) \
       \( -clone 0 -crop 23x16+92+74  \) \
       \( -clone 0 -crop 23x16+100+80 \) \
       -delete 0 +append out.jpg
```

Comment: Hi @Mark, 
Thanks for your solution. It works, but the problem is after resizing the imagemagick does the image conversion, and in the next step it does again. I will be really much effort because in the real solution i have minimum 150 crops and max 1000 crops per command.

Comment: Maybe ask another question that actually shows what hou really want to do with the full, bigger picture. Maybe you would be better off in Perl or using an MPC or MPR.