# ImageMagick v7 distortion

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, distortion

I have installed ImageMagickV6 on my linux machine since forever, and recently setup this command to process a distorted image:

```
convert ref_25X.tif -virtual-pixel Gray +distort Plane2Cylinder 60 MIFF:- | \
convert - -rotate 90 MIFF:- | \
convert - -virtual-pixel Gray +distort Plane2Cylinder 50 MIFF:- | \ 
convert - -rotate -92 MIFF:- | \
convert - -distort Perspective '10,10 10,10 10,1000 10,1000 1280,10 1280,30 1280,1000 1280,980' MIFF:- | \
convert - -shave 80x100 plane1.png
```

Since the final application will run on a windows machine I copied it there, to discover that on that machine the installed version is IMv7. And with v7 they radically changed the way they deal with the command line, as described in https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php.

So I tried to re-learn how to deal with distortion correction in **V7**, and discovered that the index page https://imagemagick.org/index.php links to the **V6** help https://imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/ so it is unusable!!!

Can somebody show me how to deal with this in IMv7 ?

Comment: Ugh! Why do you do it that way at all??? It’s very ugly. Is there a reason for it?

Comment: ugly why? I have to correct for a barrel distortion along both directions, correct for a small misorientation, and last correct a bit of perspective: it is an image acquired by a microscope with some misalignment in the optics...

Comment: You can probably remove every occurrence of `MIFF:- | convert -` and it will still work. You are needlessly writing every stage of processing through a pipe and starting a new process to read it, when you already had the image in memory anyway! Here's an example of doing several things to one image https://stackoverflow.com/a/28109569/2836621

Comment: If you have to correct for barrel distortion, why are you not using -distort barrel. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#barrel

Comment: Thanks a lot @MarkSetchell, that streamlined a lot my linux command - it works perfectly!

Comment: @fmw42 yes, I discovered Barrel after having used Plane2Cylinder succesfully, I'm investigating it right now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will start with this as a first stab and improve it if you provide a sample of what the input and output images are supposed to look like, and if you tell me what errors you get on your Windows box with it:

```
magick ref_25X.tif -virtual-pixel Gray ^
   +distort Plane2Cylinder 60.         ^
   -rotate 90                          ^
   +distort Plane2Cylinder 50          ^
   -rotate -92                         ^
   -distort Perspective "10,10 10,10 10,1000 10,1000 1280,10 1280,30 1280,1000 1280,980" ^
   -shave 80x100 plane1.png
```

I don't use Windows, but I believe it uses the caret (`^`) as the line continuation character, and I believe it gets very unhappy about parameters in single quotes. If anyone knows different, please ping me.

Comment: Yes, that command will work in Windows *except* there is a space after the caret at the end of the "`-virtual-pixel Gray +distort Plane2Cylinder 50`" line. Remove that space. Also, it should only need one virtual pixel setting if it uses that same setting through the various distorts.

Comment: @GeeMack Well spotted, thank you. I think I have made all the corrections as you suggest.

Comment: Thanks @MarkSetchell, I'm on my way to testing it right now... can you just explain (V7 syntax is still obscure to me) why some args are `+distort` and some `-distort` ?

Comment: I'm not sure what I can add to the documentation on distortions https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#distort If you have any specific questions, I suspect @GeeMack is something of an expert in that area.

Comment: With "-distort" the operation doesn't change the dimensions of the viewport. Using "+distort" with the "+" modifies the viewport to fit the result of the distortion. There are several exceptions where it wouldn't make sense to change/not-change the viewport dimensions.